# Mysql database got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP and MSQL innoDb but after executing some queries it close the database connection and gives below error in nysql error log file:

```
   **[Warning] Aborted connection 2930856 to db: 'mydatabase' user: 'testuset' host: '10.***.0.**' (Got an error reading communication packets)**
```

I have changed the configuration of 'max_allowed_packet', 'wait_timeout', 'max_execution_time' and some other settings as well but nothing helps me.

Comment: This answer might answer your question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40899/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets

Comment: I have done the changes mentioned in above link but still issue is same.